# How do I upload an image in a header?

Tags: html

I am working with a template and when I replace the name of the picture on the template (there is no file extension on it and it is not preceded by img wording), the template picture goes away but it is not replaced with my picture.  This picture is part of a header and both images are located in the same folder and have the same JPG file extension.  I have tried posting the code but I am getting a message that the code is not properly formatted.  I am a novice at this and not at all literate in coding language so please be patient.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please be more specific, we don't even know which template...

Comment: Can you post the html?